# How to use an image/logo as loader

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, effects

Im interested to make a loading page like the one on this site:
http://www.weinbau-trummer.at
Maybe the solution is to slide another image over it with some opacity?

Comment: Yep, go ahead and try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for **[Progress.js](http://usablica.github.io/progress.js/)**

It can be a good starting point for you to begin with instead of starting from scratch. It contains many different progress styles, play around with it until you make or find the one you're looking for.